# Docker and Nginx: port 80 and 403: address already in use

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops

I have a VPS server runs on Ubuntu, I am running multiple Django projects with Nginx and Gunicorn.

Recently, I decided to deploy my latest project with Docker.

Everything is working, except the port 80. I can run the website on example.com:1330 but once I change it to 80, I get this error:

```
  err: ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint project-nginx (a4417bdb121b0afb1e57e11b68dd0eb74f770ed74f654a2722f4cd74121): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
err: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here is a part of my:

- **docker-compose.yml**

  nginx:
  container_name: portfolio-nginx
  restart: unless-stopped
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
  - "80:80" # doesn't work
  - "1330:80" # works
- **Nginx**

  upstream project {
  server project-django:8000;
  }

  server {

  ```
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://project;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_redirect off;
   }

   location /static/ {
       root /code;
   }

   location /media/ {
       root /code;
   }
  ```

  }

I thought the problem is I have Nginx already running on port 80:

```
sudo netstat -ntulp | grep 80
```

Once I kill the process the docker website ***works on port 80***. But I **lose** the other Django projects that doesn't run on docker.

Please, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Django project takes port 80, there is 3 main solutions:

- Launch Django on other port
- Launch this project on other port
- Place projects on different subdomains using NGINX

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the port of this project. but should I leave it in that format: example.com:1330 ??

Comment: Yes, because of your project placed on port 1330 you should connect with http(s)://example.com:1330

Comment: Isn't ugly ? XD

Comment: You can use third way, different subdomains looks better than explicit port